# Doxygen cref doesn't work without full namespace (even for classes in same namespace)

Tags: c#, documentation, doxygen, xml-documentation

I'm trying to use Doxygen (v1.10.0) to produce documentation for my C# code, but I can't get cross reference links to work, except if I qualify them with the full namespace. For references to other classes in the same namespace, this feels unnecessary and is less readable.

I can't find any info about this. I've seen issues mentioning various issues with Doxygen cref for generic classes (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/5489) and links to different namespaces (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/8487) but nothing about it not working for plain non-generic classes in the same namespace.

Here is the documentation source:

File GenerationSource.cs

```
namespace Runevision.LayerGen {
    /// <summary>
    /// Unity component that creates a <see cref="TopLayerDependency"/>. <br/>
    /// Unity component that creates a \ref TopLayerDependency. <br/>
    /// Unity component that creates a <see cref="Runevision.LayerGen.TopLayerDependency"/>. <br/>
    /// Unity component that creates a \ref Runevision.LayerGen.TopLayerDependency.
    /// </summary>
    public class GenerationSource : MonoBehaviour { }
}
```

File TopLayerDependency.cs

```
namespace Runevision.LayerGen {
    /// <summary>
    /// All generation starts with one or more top level dependencies at the root.
    /// </summary>
    public class TopLayerDependency { }
}
```

And this is the output (you can see in the sidebar that GenerationSource and TopLayerDependency are in the same namespace):
[image]

(I'm using Doxygen Awesome theme, but I checked and the issue is the same without it.)

What am I missing?

Edit:

Here are the settings used that differ from the defaults (output of doxygen -x Doxyfile):

```
PROJECT_NAME           = LayerProcGen
PROJECT_NUMBER         = v0.1.0
PROJECT_BRIEF          = "Layer-based infinite procedural generation"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = Doxygen
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = YES
HIDE_COMPOUND_REFERENCE= YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = NO
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.cs \
                         *.markdown \
                         *.md
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                = Unity/SaveState/FileBasedPlayerPrefs \
                         doxygen-awesome-css
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = */UnitTests/*
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = README.md
HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET  = doxygen-awesome-css/doxygen-awesome.css \
                         doxygen-awesome-css/doxygen-awesome-sidebar-only.css
HTML_COLORSTYLE        = LIGHT
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
CLASS_GRAPH            = TEXT
```

Comment: With the given information I don't even get the links in case of a full specified names. Please complete the example so the image represents the information based on the info you give and also the result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile` (i.e. the settings different from the default settings).

Comment: @albert I've edited the post to include the settings you asked for. As for the other request "Please complete the example so the image represents the information based on the info you give" I don't know what you mean. It sounds like you're asking for a repro project, but that doesn't sound appropriate for StackOverflow? Or what information do you mean exactly?

Comment: @albert I added the source for the referenced file as well. I tested locally making a project with only those two files as listed, and it creates the same output as I showed in the image (of course with all the other classes gone in the sidebar etc.) The references with fully qualified namespaces work and the class names alone do not work. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I triede with a bit of an equivalent cpp version and here it does work. Maybe a problem with the `.`versus `::`  in doxygen. Best is to create an issue in the doxygen issue tracker on GitHub.

Comment: @albert Ok I've filed a bug report here: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/10766 I just don't understand how something so fundamental can be broken, so I hoped it was due to me having done something wrong on my end. But I simplified the setup down to using just the default Doxygen settings with no modifications, and it still reproduces.

Comment: I'm wondering as well, but C# is a little bit less used (by the developers of doxygen) than Cpp hence the possibility that it is missed.